# Subclassing NSTextField to forward first responder can't find destination responder?

Tags: subclass, nstextfield, becomefirstresponder

I'm subclassing NSTextField in order to have it make another field be first responder instead of itself. I had the field set to refuse first responder but then the window gets it and the user has to find the proper field intuitively, and that could lead to confusion.

My sub-class code contains this:

```
#import "MyTextField.h"
#import "MyController.h"    //which declares: @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{
     [_window makeFirstResponder:otherField];
     return NO;
}
@end
```

The problem is Xcode doesn't find 'otherField' which is defined in my .xib, Xcode says it's 'undeclared' here.

Someday I will have the time to convert the project to Swift, and I will be less of a beginner, but please bear with my ignorance.  Please help!  How do I make 'otherField' findable in the sub-class code?

Comment: When and why do you want to change the first responder?

Comment: I have a small NSTextField positioned visually on top of a larger NSTextField which is for data entry. The smaller field is for giving error info or rarely other responses to the user regarding what has been entered. The smaller field refuses first responder and does not draw its background, so the text in the larger field underneath can be seen and edited.

Comment: I've taken this approach because of extreme constraints on presentation space, and the popover technique is aesthetically inappropriate.

My problem is that when the user wants to select the larger field but happens to click the mouse over the area of smaller field, the first responder status does not migrate to the entry field, it goes nowhere and the user is left to guess what should be done.

Comment: Subclass `NSTextField` for the smaller field. Override `hitTest:` and return `nil`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Willeke!  So simple, so sweet, works perfectly.  As in any science, simple is elegant, simple is the best solution.